# Окно PyQt закрывается после запуска

Tags: python, python-2.x, pyqt4, webkit

Такой вот код:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore,QtWebKit,QtScript
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
web=QtWebKit.QWebView()
web.setGeometry(100,50,800,480)
web.setWindowTitle('MyBrowser')
web.load(QtCore.QUrl('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/'))
web.show()
```

Открывается окно на секунду и сразу закрывается. Как я могу это исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить еще одну строку: sys.exit(app.exec_())

Comment: Сработало, теперь не закрывается.

Comment: Попробуйте : Alt+F4

Comment: Нет вы не правильно поняли) Я имел ввиду ошибка пропала.

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore,QtWebKit,QtScript
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    web=QtWebKit.QWebView()
    web.setGeometry(100,50,800,480)
    web.setWindowTitle('MyBrowser')
    web.load(QtCore.QUrl('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/'))
    web.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```